# CLEditor - How to display raw HTML as formatted markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cleditor

I use CLEditor on an application and I'm facing a problem showing the formatted contents of the textarea. The response I receive from server looks similar to this:

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Number of customers:</span> <span style="font-weight: bold;">34</span><br>
```

I'd like to display this snippet on the page as formatted HTML:

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get this right but :

```
$('#somediv').html(response);
```